# Is there a way to distort mesh to face area?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to distort mesh to face area in Geometry nodes, like Tissue add-on does?

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html

I have this setup as a start, but have no idea what to do next:

[image]

Comment: ok, i don't get it. You do already the replacement of the faces with your objects...so what do you mean with distort? You have all information of the faces you are replacing...so you can do anything with it afterwards what you like.

Comment: Distort means that each object is distorted in the way that it covers all initial face area, like in my screenshot on the right.

Comment: I think this is often called Mesh Quelting and is not possible with geometry nodes yet as far as I know. Svershok used to allow this, I think

Comment: i am pretty sure it is possible, but you have to use a lot of mathematics and calculations ;) Although i cannot prove it - i am sure someone can...maybe Quellenform, Robin, Gorgious....some of our genius minds here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nodegroup that can do this:

https://bbbn19.gumroad.com/l/grrnv

[image]